# Does np.array share memory with list when the "copy=False" when creating the np.array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = np.array(a, copy=False)
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a[0] = 0
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a
[0, 2, 3]
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3])
```

I was expecting a and b share memory when "copy=False", judging by the argument name "copy".

Comment: Try the same thing but with `a` as a numpy array

Comment: I'd expect the opposite. Since you specify that it should not be a copy...

Comment: @NielsNet that's not what `copy=False` means

Comment: @NielsNet It's a little confusing here, but doesn't "not copy" means "share"?

Comment: @user3483203 That works as expected. So that "copy" argument is for np.array argument rather than list argument?

Comment: @HelinWang it has to do with what `copy=False` looks for.  It doesn't mean it *won't* make a copy, it means it won't make a copy if certain requirements are met.  Converting from a list to a numpy array is one of the cases where it *will* return a copy

Comment: A brief description can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), though it's not the most detailed